# How to Start multiple windows Services from asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to **restart** a set of windows services which are running on my local computer.
I want to **restart** all these services at once when i click a button in my asp.net application ?

I would appreciate if any one can help me out .

As of now i am able to implement the scenario for restarting a single windows service by using
Service Controller Class.

Comment: What's wrong with putting your current implementation in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a loop in iterating through each service name. Create a ServiceController for each service name and restart it there.

```
List<string> serviceList = //however you get all of the services you want to start, put them in here.

foreach(string serviceName in serviceList)
{
   ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName);
   ....

   controller.Restart();
}
```

To use a batch file use:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToBatchFile);
```

You can manage the process by using intellisense and a little curiosity. Also, here is an msdn article I found for you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx

To hide the command prompt and have more control over the process, use the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo class and pass its object to the Process.Start method. You can even catch the output from the batch file inside your program.

Comment: Im thinking in the lines of making a batch file then call the batch file from the application ? But i am not sure how to call a batch file from asp.net/c# application ...

Comment: so I assume you have already and/or know how to write the batch file and you just want to call it from your web app?

Comment: yes i already have the batch file ready...i need to know how to call in web app ?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToBatchFile);

Comment: Thanks a lot its working fine.But the only problem is the command prompt window pops up ...

Comment: It will only do that on the server, so the client will never see that. Also, you can probably play with those settings by fooling around with the process returned by Process.Start;